# Filter multiple rows of a CSV in D3.js and update filter on keyboard input

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, d3.js

I'm having some issues with filtering `csv` data and updating some `SVG`'s in `D3.js`.

### Issue 1

On load I want to filter multiple rows out of a csv. 
I succeeded with loading the data and filtering just one row. Then I tried a similar approach for multiple rows but this didn't work.

```
d3.csv("sample-data.csv", function(data){
  date = data.filter(function(row) {
      return row['YYYYMMDD'] == '20100901';
  })

  period = data.filter(function(row){
    for (var i = 1950; i < 2013; i++) {
      return row['YYYYMMDD'] == (i +"0901");
    } 
  });

  createVis();
}
```

### Issue 2:

Based on user input (left/right key down) I want to change the filtered date and period and update some SVG's.

Example:
Current date is: 20100903.
User taps right arrow key, date changes to the row that contains 20100904 in the YYYYMMDD column and period changes along with it like in my for loop of issue 1.

Im just simply stuck on this one as I don't know how to structure my code.

### Sample of my csv data:

```
YYYYMMDD, DDVEC, FHVEC, FG  
20100901, 31, 51, 57
20100902, 245, 20, 51
20100903, 279, 51, 62
20100904, 220, 36, 46
20100905, 284, 26, 41
```

Note that my csv will eventually contain a lot more data.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How does what you currently have not work?

Comment: Issue 1 only returns the value where row['YYMMDD'] == '19500901' instead of all the 63 rows I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  period = data.filter(function(row){
    for (var i = 1950; i < 2013; i++) {
      return row['YYYYMMDD'] == (i +"0901");
    } 
  });
```

Won't get a chance to iterate over all the values of i since the return statement will be triggered on the first iteration. To keep your structure mostly intact, you could make a small modification:

```
  period = data.filter(function(row){
    for (var i = 1950; i < 2013; i++) {
      if (row['YYYYMMDD'] == (i +"0901")) { return true; }
    }
    return false; 
  });
```

True will be returned only if there is a match; if the loop finishes with no matches False will be returned.

To improve the structure, simplify what you're checking for:

```
  period = data.filter(function(row){
    var dateNum = +row['YYYYMMDD'];
    return 19500901 <= dateNum && dateNum <= 20130901;
  });
```

Here, your string date is converted to an integer with `+` and simple arithmetic (which isn't possible to do on strings since they use lexicographic comparisons) is done to check if the date is in range.

Ideally, your dates should be represented with [actual dates](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) - if your date is in the right format, everything is much easier. To convert the date strings to date objects:

```
period.forEach(function(d){
  d.date = d3.format('%Y%m%d').parse(d.date);
})
```

To check if a given row has a date meeting the critera you've specified:

```
   row.date.getDate() == 1   && row.getMonth() == 8 
&& 1950 <= row.getFullYear() && row.getFullYear() <= 2012
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Your first solution works. The improved structure you suggest doesn't do what I need. it returns all rows between the values 19500901 and 20130901 instead of only the 0901 of the years between 1950 and 2013. Is there a way to make this improved structure work too?

Comment: Working with dates will make your life a lot easier; see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is some great help.