# D3 data parsing and filtering out

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a pretty large csv file, containing lots of data and I'd like to draw some graphs using only some kinds of data contained in the csv, to display the differences between different types of stuff.

I read the API for d3 but couldn't really get if it could be possible to do so, for example as I'm working with fonts I'd like to use only the data from the *Normal* weights in the csv, but don't really know/couldn't find any hints on how to do so.

I saw a similar question on here [Filter multiple rows of a CSV in D3.js and update filter on keyboard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002979/filter-multiple-rows-of-a-csv-in-d3-js-and-update-filter-on-keyboard-input) but wanted to know if it will work also on different values than dates, or if there's another way that I don't know of. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Once you have the data, you can process it to your liking with Javascript, so any kind of filtering is possible. To give a more concrete answer, we'll need to know what exactly you want to do and what your data looks like.

Comment: I wanted to filter out some data, I found the answer simply using .filter(function () {}) after calling the dataset. It was pretty simple but I couldn't find any kind of documentation on the d3 apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out I just needed to add

`.filter(function (d) { // what I need to keep })`

In the .data(dataset) loading of data. Pretty simple but couldn't find any documentation about that so I didn't expect it to be so straightforward.